# Calling Multiple Controller and passing data among themselves

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

For a long time, I am developing projects with Spring Framework. 
I was wondering if it is possible that calling multiple controller and passing data among themselves. Note: Controllers can also be using by oneself.

Comment: Sure, but it would be a questionable design. Controllers should rather call common services.

Comment: ...What? Why would a controller *ever* call another controller?

Comment: It's a good question. As  far as i understand, you want to handling controllers like interceptors, but they can be called and being used by single-handed.